# Tried installing a program via SSH but didn't let it finish—now Ubuntu server is unreachable

Tags: networking, server, software-installation, ssh

I tried installing `whereami`, but it stayed at 90% for a long time (too long and I had to run somewhere), so I exited the ssh connection with <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

This is the relevant output on the last two lines:

```
Setting up whereami (0.3.34-0.3) ...
packet_write_wait: Connection to 104.x.x.x port 22: Broken pipe
```

Now I can't access the Ubuntu (16.04.2 x64) server in any way through ssh:

```
ssh: connect to host 104.x.x.x port 22: Operation timed out
```

Pinging the server results in 100% packet loss.

I have tried rebooting the server—a "droplet" (which is just a fancy way to name a VPS on DigitalOcean)—with no luck. What can I do? This is the first time I've had to set up my own server and I'm a Mac user.

---

About DigitalOcean:

"[It's] a cloud infrastructure provider focused on simplifying web infrastructure for software developers." [FAQ](https://www.digitalocean.com/help/)

[DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) droplets are like AWS' Elastic Cloud Compute (EC2) but simpler to use for Developers.

Comment: Do you have physical access to the machine? How do you reboot it if you can't connect to it?

Comment: @terdon It is a DigitalOcean droplet (VPS). They have a button that allows you to turn off the server or Power Cycle it. Good questions that I should've added in the description. I'll edit it. Thanks!

Comment: So this is some sort of dedicated hardware? Which you have *physical* access to? Please explain what the thing is, not all of us will know what a "DigitalOcean droplet (VPS)" is. I certainly don't, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but this is still not clear. I assume that DigitalOcean is some sort of cloud service provider. Is that so? You mentioned a button, does that mean that you have physical access to the machine? I still don't know what this system you are using is.

Comment: @terdon Yes, it's a cloud service provider. I do have quasi-physical access in that way (an on/off button) and I have access to a console which is "will open up a console VNC connection to [my] Droplet and is the equivalent of plugging a monitor and keyboard directly to [my] virtual server."

Comment: OK, so you don't have physical access then. I guess. Do they provide any other way of accessing the machine? Can you restore to a previous, working state? Have you tried emailing their support?

Comment: No, wait, "equivalent of plugging a monitor and keyboard directly to [my] virtual server."? What happens then? Can you see the machine booting? Please put all this information in your question, it is quite tiring having to drag it out of you in the comments like this. We're not affiliated with digital ocean so we need to know what options you have available.

Comment: @terdon, I understand that my question isn't as simple as I thought it was. I thought there would be an alternative to ssh-ing into the server, such as `screen`-ing into it (which I have no idea what it does, btw, but I read somewhere that it's another way to access a server). I ended up just destroying that server and starting anew. Thank you for your input! (No pun intended).

Comment: Ah, well. That might be the simplest solution then :) As for `screen`, it';s essentially a fancy terminal (very fancy), it would still need ssh to connect. Anyway, if you ended up reinstalling, I'll close the question as non-reproducible. Sorry if I was a bit brusque with you.

Comment: @terdon Haha. Yeah, no problem, thanks for your time either way! To show my gratitude, I read some of your answers to other questions and I found them quite enlightening—so I upvoted them. 